# XML to XML with XSLT- Add, Remove, Modify Elements and Attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I want to change from one XML (XHTML) file to another using XSLT. In the new XML file I have to remove/add/modify some elements. So for that I created one `identity.xsl` file, which copies the entire source file and then I created a new XSLT which includes `identity.xsl` and then in that new XSLT I'm trying to do the modifications. I'm able to eliminate a few attributes, which are not required, by passing a template match which does nothing but I'm unable to add the new attributes in the existing tags and also unable to add the new elements at the specific location (with closing tags at particular location).

My Original file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="o">
    <div id="nd">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="TF id="id12">
      <element1 name="abc" src="abc.jpg"></script>
      <input type="radio" id="1" event="xyz">
      <div class="q">
        <br/>
        <div id="ta3" class="block">
          <span style="a">ABC</span>
        </div>
        <br/>T <input/> F <input/>
        <div id="sf">
          <div id="ta3">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Required file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<!--HAVE TO AD THESE TWO ELEMENTS-->
<element add="xyz" id="23">
<element add="xyz" id="24">

<!--ADD ATTRIBUTES IN BODY TAG-->
<body onLoad="ada" bgcolor="pink">

  <div id="o">
    <div id="nd">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="TF id="id12">

      <!--HAVE TO UPATE THE VALUE OF SRC ATTRIBUTE -->
      <element1 name="abc" src="xyz.jpg"></script>

      <!--ADD THIS FORM ELEMENT WITH ATTRIBUTE-->
      <form name="form">
        <input type="radio" id="1" event="xyz">
        <div class="q">
          <br/>
          <div id="ta3" class="block">
            <span style="a">ABC</span>
          </div>

          <br/>T 
          <!--ADD TABLE/TR/TD TAG-->
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              </td>
              F <input/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <div id="sf">
            <div id="ta3">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--ADD INPUT TAG-->
        <input type="submit" value="Done"/>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--CLOSE FORM TAG-->
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- Import the identity transformation. -->
  <xsl:import href="identity.xsl"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="body">
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <body onLoad="ada" bgcolor="pink"></body>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--REMOVES THE MATCHING ATTRIBUTE and DOES THE JOB-->
  <xsl:template match="@attr"> </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="input">
    <xsl:element name="input">
      <xsl:attribute name="type">submit</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">Done</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems you're running into?

Comment: @Michael I'm unable to add new elements with attributes and adding new attributes to the existing elements. However, I'm able to remove/update the attributes. For example-
I have to add two elements just after head tag and add new attributes to the body tag but I'm not able to do that.

Comment: There are a few errors in you input XML. For example the script tag is not balanced. Please correct so we can understand your intentions.

Comment: RahuID, as I was fixing your formatting, I can tell you, clearly, that your XML input is totally invalid. Maybe you want to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input document was so full of formation errors, I've had to take the risk of guessing your intentions. Please see the transform solution below. I deliberately did not include the insertion of the table elements around your comment "ADD TABLE/TR/TD TAG", as this section seemed so nutty that any solution that I provided for you here would likely be a wrong interpretation of your required rules of transformation.

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:body">
  <element add="xyz" id="23" />
  <element add="xyz" id="24" />
 <body onLoad="ada" bgcolor="pink">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:element1[@name='abc']/@src">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">xyz.jpg</xsl:attribute>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:input[@id='1']">
  <form name="form">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::xhtml:div[1]" mode="inside-form"/> 
  </form>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:div[ preceding-sibling::xhtml:*[1]
   /self::xhtml:input[@id='1']]"/>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:div" mode="inside-form">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 <input type="submit" value="Done"/> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**... will take this input document ...**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="o">
  <div id="nd">
   <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="TF" id="id12">
   <element1 name="abc" src="abc.jpg"/>
   <input type="radio" id="1" event="xyz"/>
   <div class="q">
    <br/>
    <div id="ta3" class="block">
     <span style="a">ABC</span>
    </div>
    <br/>T <input/> F <input/>
    <div id="sf">
     <div id="ta3">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**...and yield this output document ...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <element add="xyz" id="23" />
  <element add="xyz" id="24" />
  <body onLoad="ada" bgcolor="pink">
    <div id="o">
      <div id="nd">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="TF" id="id12">
        <element1 name="abc" src="xyz.jpg" />
        <form name="form">
          <input type="radio" id="1" event="xyz" />
          <div class="q">
            <br />
            <div id="ta3" class="block">
              <span style="a">ABC</span>
            </div>
            <br />T <input /> F <input /><div id="sf"><div id="ta3" /></div></div>
          <input type="submit" value="Done" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SeanBDurkin Thanks a lot for the reply. I'll do it in the way you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly. Now I can try some modifications. :)

Comment: I have a question. Like in the above source XHTML, there is one-
<element1 name="abc" src="abc.jpg"/>, while in my complete source file I have one more along with that like <element1 name="abc" src="pqr.jpg"/> and one inside 'head' tag like <element1 name="abc" src="lmn.jpg"/>, So when I apply the above XSLT then it changes the value of source everywhere and makes it xyz.jpg while I have to change only where src="abc.jpg". So can you please tell me that how can I achieve that? Thanking you!

Comment: I tried something like this-
<xsl:template match="xhtml:element1[@src='abc.jpg']">
But its not working out, it removes the entire element1 tag where src="abc.jpg"

Comment: Hi Rahul. Please post your question as another question. I and others will look at it. For best results, provide a sample input, expected output, XSLT version (1.0 or 2.0) and the rules of transformation. Also make sure that xml listings are well-formed and free of error. I am looking forward to seeing your new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the consideration. I'll put the new question very soon. :)

Comment: Hi Sean, I have posted a new question as per your suggestion, pleas find it here-
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606596/xml-to-xml-conversion-with-xslt-add-delete-modify>. Looking forward for your valuable help again. Thanking you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I can't stand XSL-T.  It's too hard to read.

My preference is to create a Velocity template of the XML I want to produce and use [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) to map from the old XML to the new.  It's easier to visualize and works just as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Sorry I'm new to XSLT so I don't know about the Velocity template of the XML. Can you please suggest that how can I do that?

Comment: Check the hyperlink and start reading how to use Velocity.  It's relatively easy.